# Get internal class type for T parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var cache = this._memoryCache;
cache.Set("a", "value of a");            
BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;

FieldInfo field = cache.GetType().GetField("_entries", bindFlags);
var reflactionResult = field.GetValue(cache) as Dictionary<object, ?>;
```

The version now is ASP.NET Core 1 RC1. I want to get a private field from  `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` there is source code [aspnet/Caching git](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs).

The field I want is

```
private readonly Dictionary<object, CacheEntry> _entries;
```

I can get it by

```
field.GetValue(cache);
```

(in my above code) but it type is `object` and I want to make it as `Dictionary<object, CacheEntry>` so I can get the value, by the way what all I want is in `object` not in `CacheEntry`.

But the `CacheEntry` is internal class then I stuck. In my last line in above code I have a question mark I don't know how to set it.

Comment: It's an internal class, so you won't be able to have it statically typed. You could convert it into a `Dictionary<object, ICacheEntry>`, though.

Comment: This make sense! Let me check

Comment: Experiencing the same impediment with release 1.0.1